# Changing the partition key of a live IMap in Hazelcast (partition migration)

Tags: hazelcast

I'd like to change the way one of my maps is partitioned in Hazelcast. Can Hazelcast handle this safely for an existing distributed map if I start replacing nodes with new nodes using a different partitioning strategy?

Say I have Customers in my map partitioned by CustomerId but I want to start partitioning them with a PartitionAwareKey which keeps the key as CustomerId but changes the PartitionKey to be the customer's ZIP code.

It's easy to do with PartitionAwareKey but I see no docs on how this works for migrating an existing distributed map.

It seems like this will simply add new items to the map as PartitionAwareKey  uses both key and partitionKey in its equals method.

If I made my own ParitionAware without using the partitionKey as part of the equals/hashcode implementation would I be able to live replace the way the items are partitioned without causing inconsistency in the map access?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you meant by "the way map is partitioned" and "partitioning strategy"? It is not really clear as to what is being attempted here.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. I updated the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are some anomalies in documentation, let me attempt to provide some clarity here - all nodes in the cluster need to have same partition strategy and all related configurations. In other words, you can not have some nodes running with different partition strategy than others.

Therefore, to inject new strategy you need to restart the entire cluster with new settings. However, since a cluster restart does not seem to be a desired option, you can try injecting new configurations into the cluster through [User Code Deployment](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0/manual/html-single/index.html#member-user-code-deployment-beta) and see if that works.

Note: I personally have not tried changing partition strategy through user code deployment, so it would be interesting to see what you find.